# Exception in WCF with UserName Authentication

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication

I'm trying to authenticate a WCF with custom UserName and Password authentication. I followed [this tutorial by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/user-name-password-validator). On local development everything worked well, but I cannot connect to the service once deployed in the server. 
Whenever I try to access a method in the service it throws this exception in the client:

> The secure channel cannot be opened because an error was generated in the security negotiation with the remote end. It may be because EndpointIdentity is missing or incorrectly specified in the EndpointAddress element that is used to create the channel. Verify that the EndpointIdentity element specified or implied in EndpointAddress correctly identifies the remote endpoint.

It seems I have done everything that is required. First, I created a Certificate in the client
with this PowerShell commands:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName desasqlapps01.ad.impi.gob.mx -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My -KeySpec KeyExchange


 $CertPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String “PruebaCertificadoAutoFirma” -Force –AsPlainText
 Export-PfxCertificate -Cert cert:\LocalMachine\My\E7A3FCD624E6FBD74B1EB346F0A8E0CA38FA24A3 - 
 FilePath C:\testcerttramitemixto.pfx -Password $CertPassword
```

I created a class that derives from `UserNamePasswordValidator` in the service and the relevant parts of the configuration of the service are:

```
    <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" maxRequestLength="2147483647"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WS_TramiteMixto.IServiceTramiteMixto">

        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress ="http://desasqlapps01.ad.impi.gob.mx/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address=""
                    binding="wsHttpBinding"
                    contract="WS_TramiteMixto.IServiceTramiteMixto"></endpoint>
        <!--<endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />-->

      </service>

    </services>
    <bindings>

      <!--<basicHttpBinding>

        <binding maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" receiveTimeout="00:30:00" sendTimeout="00:30:00">

          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>-->

      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" receiveTimeout="00:30:00" sendTimeout="00:30:00">
          <security mode="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" establishSecurityContext="true" />
          </security>
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"/>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceCredentials>


            <!--The serviceCredentials behavior allows one to
          specify a custom validator for username/password
          combinations.
          -->

            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
                                    customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="WS_TramiteMixto.TramiteMixtoPaseValidator, WS_TramiteMixto" />


            <!--The serviceCredentials behavior allows one to define a service certificate. A service certificate is used by a client to authenticate the service and provide message protection. You must specify a server certificate when passing username/passwords to encrypt the information as it is sent on the wire. Otherwise the username and password information would be sent as clear text. This configuration references the "localhost" certificate installed during the setup instructions.
          -->

            <serviceCertificate findValue="desasqlapps01.ad.impi.gob.mx" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
          </serviceCredentials>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph ="2147483647"/>
          <!-- Para evitar revelar información de los metadatos, establezca el valor siguiente en false antes de la implementación -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" policyVersion="Policy12" />
          <!-- Para recibir detalles de los errores de la excepción para la depuración, establezca el valor siguiente en true. Establézcalo en false antes de la implementación para evitar revelar información de la excepción -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="wsHttpBinding" scheme="http"/>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Then the client was configured like this:

```
<behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webHttp">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="ClientCertificateBehavior">
          <clientCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate>

           <!-- setting the certificatevalidationmode to peerorchaintrust means that if the certificate
            is in the user's trusted people store, then it will be trusted without performing a
            validation of the certificate's issuer chain. this setting is used here for convenience so that the
            sample can be run without having to have certificates issued by a certification authority (ca).
            this setting is less secure than the default, chaintrust. the security implications of this
            setting should be carefully considered before using peerorchaintrust in production code. -->

              <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerOrChainTrust" />
            </serviceCertificate>
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>

      </endpointBehaviors>
<bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService1" />
            <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IServiceTramiteMixto">
              <security mode="Message">
                <message clientCredentialType="UserName" establishSecurityContext="true" negotiateServiceCredential="true" />
              </security>
            </binding>
          </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<endpoint address="http://desasqlapps01.ad.impi.gob.mx/WS_TramiteMIxto/ServiceTramiteMixto.svc"
  binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IServiceTramiteMixto"
  contract="ServicioTramiteMixto.IServiceTramiteMixto" name="WSHttpBinding_IServiceTramiteMixto">
      <!--<endpoint address="http://desasqlapps01.ad.impi.gob.mx/WS_TramiteMIxto/ServiceTramiteMixto.svc"
        binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IServiceTramiteMixto"
        contract="ServicioTramiteMixto.IServiceTramiteMixto" name="WSHttpBinding_IServiceTramiteMixto" behaviorConfiguration="ClientCertificateBehavior">-->
        <!--<identity>
          <dns value="http://desasqlapps01.ad.impi.gob.mx/"></dns>
        </identity>-->
        <identity>
          <certificate encodedValue="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" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
```

The certificate I have placed both in the Trusted People store in the client and in the Personal store of the current user in the server, but I get that exception and I can't invoke any of the methods in the service. I also enabled tracing in the service but nothing gets logged, so it seems that the client cannot even access the service.

I've read that this error can be caused by LoadBalancing in IIS, where I host the service as an application, according to [this post](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/156994/WCF-Secure-Channel-cannot-be-opened-Load-Balancing) But Microsoft states that to deal with Load Balancing in IIS you should use Secure Sessions, from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/load-balancing?redirectedfrom=MSDN) Which I'm already doing in the type of security in the service bindings:  `<security mode="Message">`

One of the requirements is to authenticate all incoming requests of this service.

**UPDATE:** 
**By the way, the commented endpoint that reads `<endpoint address="http://desasqlapps01.ad.impi.gob.mx/WS_TramiteMIxto/ServiceTramiteMixto.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IServiceTramiteMixto" contract="ServicioTramiteMixto.IServiceTramiteMixto" name="WSHttpBinding_IServiceTramiteMixto" behaviorConfiguration="ClientCertificateBehavior">` is the actual configuration, the comments were added later.**

@Ross Bush thank you for your answer
I edited the web config in the service to look like this:

```
         <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" receiveTimeout="00:30:00" sendTimeout="00:30:00">
          <security mode="Transport">
<transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
        </security>
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"/>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph ="2147483647"/>
          <!-- Para evitar revelar información de los metadatos, establezca el valor siguiente en false antes de la implementación -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" policyVersion="Policy12" />
          <!-- Para recibir detalles de los errores de la excepción para la depuración, establezca el valor siguiente en true. Establézcalo en false antes de la implementación para evitar revelar información de la excepción -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="wsHttpBinding" scheme="http"/>

    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

However I wan't to know if the configuration you suggested works only in https: I'm know getting a runtime error that states

> Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding WSHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are http

and the service is not running now.

@Ross Bush nevermind, I have solved it adding

```
<add binding="wsHttpBinding" scheme="https"/>

</protocolMapping>
```

to the config at the service

Based on the comments I have received I wish to rephrase my question, specifically I want to know -if anybody can tell me-

Is my certificate valid? 
Is it possible to set up a username password validation on wcf without using ssl?

The tutorial on Microsoft only states:

> You need a server certificate with the subject name that contains the fully-qualified domain name of the machine. The configuration file for the server must be updated to reflect this new certificate name

But it doesn't say anything about using SSL or a SSL certificate.
Thanks in avance.

Comment: Yes, the answer I submitted would work under https only. I removed it as it will not solve your specific issue(s). If you go forward with that approach then you need to have an endpoint with a wsHttpBinding binding, sorry that was not clear.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use HTTPS, just like what you have configured. It really works. However, we at least specify one certificate on the server-side irrespective of using https or configuring a service certificate.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfService3.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="mybehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="mybinding" contract="WcfService3.IService1"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="mybinding">
          <security mode="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="mybehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <serviceCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" findValue="5ba5022f527e32ac02548fc5afc558de1d314cb6"/>
            <userNameAuthentication customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="WcfService3.CustUserNamePasswordVal,WcfService3" userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"/>
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

What I don't know is whether your certificate domain name corresponds to the server machine name? I suggest you generate the client proxy class by adding a service reference.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/accessing-services-using-a-wcf-client
The client generated endpoint configuration will automatically add an EndpointIdentity.

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService1">
          <security>
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://vabqia969vm:8818/Service1.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
        name="WSHttpBinding_IService1">
        <identity>
          <certificate encodedValue="blablabla" />
<!--or,using dns to identity the server -->
          <!--<dns value="vabqia969vm"/>-->
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
```

In addition, please remove the `webhttpbinding` associated configuration. This has nothing to do with the problem.
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: @AbrahamQlan I already have that configuration, as you say yourself, and when I added the service reference in VS it also generates an Identity. One question though, ¿can the certificate be self-signed, as I have done, or does it have to be of a CA?

Comment: both can. the question is that the trust relationship is supposed to be established before calling the service.  in order to do that,  on the client-side, we usually install the server certificate in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities of the certificate store. or program the certificate validation callback.

Comment: ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += delegate
            {
                return true;
            };
            ServiceReference1.ServiceClient client = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient();